# Encode user input against SQL injection

Tags: jquery, ajax

Goodmorning guys,

I'm working on a form for one of our clients. The server where the form runs on has a very strict firewall. At the moment we are running into the issue of the firewall not accepting certrain form entries because there are too many punctiation marks in the message - the firewall see's this as a possible SQL injection.

Once the submit button is clicked a AJAX request goes to a PHP file which handles all the email-sending.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/wp/actions/apply-position-mail.php',
    data: {
        job: $('input#jobtitle').val(),
        firstname: $('input#first-name').val(),
        lastname: $('input#last-name').val(),
        email: $('input#email').val(),
        phone: $('input#tel').val(),
        resume: filename,
        comments: comments
    }
});
```

Simply put i'm looking for a way in Javascript to decode/encode strings (especially the 'comments' field) so the firewall has no issue posting them.

Of course I Googled and tried different encoding JS functions but none of them did the trick.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what is getting filtered it's going to be try and pray until it works but the best chance at a proper start is to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: "The server where the form runs on has a very strict firewall". I think you should look up the definition of a firewall. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing) has a good summary. Firewalls block ports, not data. What you're actually talking about is code which validates the submitted data. This is in the PHP code, not in any firewall. I mention this only because it's useful in computing, where precision is everything, and confusion causes delays and errors, to use the correct terminology.

Comment: But anyway to answer the question it would be useful to see the PHP code which is doing the filtering, and also some examples of the kinds of things which are getting blocked. Punctuation marks are not, by themselves anyway, a means of carrying out an injection attack - are you certain that's the determining factor? If it really is, then I think that their method for preventing injection attacks is flawed, unless there is some other business reason for rejecting certain characters. If they're correctly using parameterised queries etc to write their queries it shouldn't need to be strict at all

Comment: Thank your for the different respones.

@Chase : i actually run into that one and messed around with it but couldn't make it work

Comment: @ADyson : thanks, you are right; i was just quoting what the hosting company told me. If i can't get it to work i'm going back to the hosting company. 

There is no PHP filtering, Javascript collects data from the form and uses a AJAX request to send it to a PHP file which then sends a email (through the WP_mail() function). The server blocks this AJAX-post to the PHP file.

Comment: "blocks" it how, exactly? What response and/or error message do you get when you make the ajax request? If there's "no PHP filtering" as you mention, then how is it telling you that the data is invalid? That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I get a 403:

403 Forbidden
Forbidden - You don't have permission to access [...]/apply-position-mail.php on this server.

The hosting company said the logs told them it returns this error because the 'firewall' doesnt like the punctuation (! @ # $ % . ^ etc) in the send data.

Comment: I also tried to '.serialize()' the whole form but he wouldn't allow this neither.

Answer (score 0):

Together with the hosting company we've came to a solution. This is my JS now:

```
var formArray = $('form').serializeArray();
var returnArray = {};

for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
    returnArray[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;
}

$.ajax({
    url: '[..]/apply-position-mail.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(returnArray),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data, msg) {
        console.log(msg, data);
    },
    error: function(data, msg) {
        console.log(msg, data);
    }
});
```

All the input fields and values are being collected in array and stringified before posting.

In PHP this gives me the posted data:

```
$rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$form = json_decode($rawPostData);
```